# Get count of selected column out of DataGridView

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, datagridview

What do I have:

- Filled datagridview
- Selected cells of this grid

What do I want:

- Amount of unique columns of the selected cells
- Names of these columns

What I found:

```
int selectedColumnsCount = dataGridView3.SelectedColumns.Count;
```

Somehow this piece of code isn't working in my case.

My question: How can I get the columns name and the amount of columns selected out of a `DataGridView`?

This is what I created now:

```
int selectedCellCount = dataGridView3.GetCellCount(DataGridViewElementStates.Selected);
int selectedcolumncount = dataGridView3.SelectedColumns.Count;
ArrayList arr = new ArrayList();
int j = 0;

if (selectedCellCount > 0)
{
   for (int i = 0; i < selectedCellCount; i++)
   {
      int Xcor2 = int.Parse(dataGridView3.SelectedCells[i].ColumnIndex.ToString());
      test = test + dataGridView3.Columns[Xcor2].Name;
      arr.Add(dataGridView3.Columns[Xcor2].Name);
   }
}

ArrayList arr2 = new ArrayList();
foreach (string str in arr)
{
   if (!arr2.Contains(str))
   {
      arr2.Add(str);
      j++;
   }
}
```

This is what I made myself, not that nice but its working to get the count of columns if anyone has a better way of realizing this, feel free to add

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can register for the [`SelectionChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.selectionchanged.aspx) event and process the [`SelectedCells`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.selectedcells.aspx).  For example

```
public Form1()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   dataGridView1.SelectionChanged += new EventHandler(dataGridView1_SelectionChanged);
}

HashSet<int> column_indicies = new HashSet<int>();
HashSet<string> column_names = new HashSet<string>();
int number_of_columns = 0;

void dataGridView1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   column_indicies.Clear();
   column_names.Clear();
   foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in dataGridView1.SelectedCells)
   {
      // Set of column indicies
      column_indicies.Add(cell.ColumnIndex);
      // Set of column names
      column_names.Add(dataGridView1.Columns[cell.ColumnIndex].Name);
   }
   // Number of columns the selection ranges over
   number_of_columns = column_indicies.Count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot select columns. Only one columns can be selected at a time!
Columns are the same as Rows.
Or did you mean to get those columns, which cells are slected?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is one of the way of getting column names (you can even use HeaderText property instead of Name):

```
        List<DataGridViewColumn> listOfColumns = new List<DataGridViewColumn>();
        foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in dataGridView1.SelectedCells)
        {
            DataGridViewColumn col = dataGridView1.Columns[cell.ColumnIndex] as DataGridViewColumn;
            if (!listOfColumns.Contains(col))
                listOfColumns.Add(col);
        }
        StringBuilder sb =new StringBuilder();
        foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in listOfColumns)
            sb.AppendLine(col.Name);
        MessageBox.Show("Column names of selected cells are:\n" + sb.ToString());
```